# UserNamePasswordValidator works but won't hit breakpoint

Tags: wcf, breakpoints

I have added a UserNamePasswordValidator class to my WCF Service.  It appears to work fine.  The FaultException and custom error message appears as expected when I supply wrong credentials.  And it passes without an exception with correct credentials.

My problem is that I cannot hit a breakpoint placed within the Validate method.  I can hit breakpoints everywhere else in the project.

Any suggestions?  Test code is below:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfTestService1
{
    public class Service1Authenticator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (!(userName == "testUser" && password == "testPassword"))
            {
                //Specific Exception
                //throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid Username or Password");

                //Or Specific Message
                throw new FaultException("Custom message to prove this works");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it in your gac? try this: gacutil /l | findstr /i "your-assembly-name"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I looked and this assembly is not in the GAC.

Comment: Have the exact same issue, ever found a solution?